# formalize.css buttons in ie/chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, button, formalize

I'm experiencing some problems styling buttons.

I'm using formalize.css from http://formalize.me/ and the Eric Meyer CSS Reset.

This is what happens in IE and Chrome:

[image]

The class for the buttons looks like this:

```
.paging_button
{
margin-top:2px;
width: 25px !important;
}
```

Any suggestions as to why the descriptions seem to float out of their normal position in IE and Chrome?

Comment: Are you using the javascript as well? Please specify.

Answer (score 0):

try `padding: 0px;`  current default value is... `padding: 1px 6px;` I think?

Comment: np :) Chrome's developer tools are great for this sort of thing.